# Is the NativeBase default theme dark mode-compatible?

Tags: native-base

The NativeBase [docs say](https://docs.nativebase.io/color-mode):

> By default, most components are dark mode compatible.

but I am not seeing this.

For example, this `<Input />`:

```
import {FormControl, Input, ScrollView} from 'native-base';

function Form(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <FormControl.Label>Description</FormControl.Label>
      <Input placeholder="Placeholder" />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

looks the same in both light mode and dark mode:

[image]
[image]

(I have wrapped my tree with a `NativebaseProvider`.)

Answer (score 1):

In order for NativeBase to use the system color mode, at the time of this writing (v3.4.1) you must set `useSystemColorMode` to be `true`.

```
const customTheme = extendTheme({
  config: {
      useSystemColorMode: true,
  },
});
```

and pass that custom theme to `NativeBaseProvider` (by default, `useSystemColorMode` is `false`). Otherwise you can set it yourself with `initialColorMode`:

```
const customTheme = extendTheme({
  config: {
      initialColorMode: 'light',
  },
});
```

and keep it in sync manually with [`Appearance#addChangeListener()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance#addchangelistener) or [`useColorScheme()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usecolorscheme).